# deserialize json file c#/MVC - getting a list of the properties not working

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, geojson

I'v a json file and I would like to to create a table that contains all the properties but I could not do that

My json

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "parameter_description": {
        "Temp": {
            "name": "Temp",
            "id": "http://codes.wmo.int/common/quantity-kind/_dewPointTemperature",
            "units": {
                "name": "degC",
                "id": "degC",
                "symbol": "\u00b0C"
            }
        },
        "Rain": {
            "name": "Rain",
            "id": "http://codes.wmo.int/wmdr/ObservedVariableTerrestrial/_389",
            "units": {
                "name": "degC",
                "id": "degC",
                "symbol": "\u00b0C"
            }
        }
    },
    "bbox": [
        -1.123,
        52.123,
        -1.123,
        52.123
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "Temp": [
                    42.19,
                    4.80,
           
                ],
                "Rain": [
                    13.6,
                    15.5,
          
                ],
                "ValidityTime": [
                    "2021-11-01",
                    "2021-11-01",
          
                ]
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -1.123,
                    52.123
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "456",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "Temp": [
                    5.0,
                    4.8,
       
                ],
                "Rain": [
                    12.4,
                    14.7,
        
                ],
                "ValidityTime": [
                    "2021-11-01",
                    "2021-11-01T",
      
                ]
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -1.123,
                    52.123
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like the table looks like this :

| Properties | Value | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Temp | 4.9 | 12345 |
| Rain | 12.3 | 12345 |

Note that the ID will be repeated. The issue is that that there is no 'comma' divides the properties.

Classes

```
public class Root
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
            public ParameterDescription parameter_description { get; set; }
            public List<double> bbox { get; set; }
            public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
        }

public class Properties
        {
            public List<double> Tdew { get; set; }
            public List<double> RST { get; set; }
            public List<string> ValidityTime { get; set; }
        }

public class Feature
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public Properties properties { get; set; }
            public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
            // public Geometry Coor {get;set;}
            public Point Coor {get;set;}

            public double distance {get;set;}
        }
```

Any hint?

Comment: Please post your full `JSON` string here.

Comment: @RahulSharma my json is the same of the one that I posted.. the full one is repeated and has thousands of lines

Comment: Then at least give us a snippet of the correct `JSON` string. The one that you have posted is not a correct `JSON` string

Comment: @RahulSharma I've update the json code. this one is valid. would you please try it

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be a solution for you.

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using CodeBeautify;
//
//    var welcome8 = Welcome8.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace CodeBeautify
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public partial class Welcome8
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parameter_description")]
    public ParameterDescription ParameterDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("features")]
    public Feature[] Features { get; set; }
}

public partial class Feature
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("properties")]
    public Properties Properties { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("geometry")]
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
}

public partial class Geometry
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("coordinates")]
    public double[] Coordinates { get; set; }
}

public partial class Properties
{
    [JsonProperty("Temp")]
    public double[] Temp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rain")]
    public double[] Rain { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ValidityTime")]
    public DateTimeOffset[] ValidityTime { get; set; }
}

public partial class ParameterDescription
{
    [JsonProperty("Temp")]
    public Rain Temp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Rain")]
    public Rain Rain { get; set; }
}

public partial class Rain
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Welcome8
{
    public static Welcome8 FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome8>(json, CodeBeautify.Converter.Settings);
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this Welcome8 self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, CodeBeautify.Converter.Settings);
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        Converters =
        {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
        },
    };
}

internal class ParseStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(long) || t == typeof(long?);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
        var value = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
        long l;
        if (Int64.TryParse(value, out l))
        {
            return l;
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type long");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (untypedValue == null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
            return;
        }
        var value = (long)untypedValue;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
        return;
    }

    public static readonly ParseStringConverter Singleton = new ParseStringConverter();
    }
}
```

Comment: appreciate your effort. but this is not what i'm asking